# Complement of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $X$ and $Y$ be subspaces of $V$. It is obvious that if $X\subseteq Y$, then for every subspace $W$ of $V$ such that $X+W=V$, we should have $Y+W=V$. Is the converse of it true? In other words, if for every subspace of $W$ of $V$ with $W+X=V$, we have $Y+W=V$. Then can we conclude that $X\subseteq Y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $W$ be a complement of $X+Y$ in $V$, i.e. $X+Y+W = V$, and $(X+Y) \cap W = 0$.

Then, by hypothesis, $V=Y+(Y+W)=Y+W$, so $W$ is a complement of $Y$. This implies (using Grassmann) that

$$\dim (X+Y) = \dim Y$$
so
$X+Y = Y \Rightarrow X \subseteq Y$.

Answer (score 1):

Choose a basis $x_1, x_2, \dots , x_n $ of $X$ and extend it to a basis $x_1, \dots , x_n, w_1, \dots w_n$ of $V.$ Let $W$ be the subspace generated by $w_1, \dots , w_n.$ Then $X+W=V.$ So we have $Y+W=V.$ From this it follows that $X \subseteq Y.$